# How to optimize GNU parallel for this use?

Tags: bash, parallelism, gnu-parallel

I created this script out of boredom with the sole purpose of using/testing GNU parallel so I know it's not particularly useful or optimized, but I have a script that will calculate all prime numbers up to n:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

isprime () {
    local n=$1
    ((n==1)) && return 1
    for ((i=2;i<n;i++)); do
        if ((n%i==0)); then
            return 1
        fi
    done
    printf '%d\n' "$n"
}

for ((f=1;f<=$1;f++)); do
    isprime "$f"
done
```

When run with the loop:

```
$ time ./script.sh 5000 >/dev/null

real    0m28.875s
user    0m38.818s
sys     0m29.628s
```

I would expect replacing the for loop with GNU parallel would make this run significantly faster but that has not been my experience.  On average it's only about 1 second faster:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

isprime () {
    local n=$1
    ((n==1)) && return 1
    for ((i=2;i<n;i++)); do
        if ((n%i==0)); then
            return 1
        fi
    done
    printf '%d\n' "$n"
}

export -f isprime

seq 1 $1 | parallel -j 20 -N 1 isprime {}
```

Run with parallel:

```
$ time ./script.sh 5000 >/dev/null

real    0m27.655s
user    0m38.145s
sys     0m28.774s
```

---

I'm not really interested in optimizing the `isprime()` function, I am just wondering if there is something I can do to optimize GNU parallel?

In my testing `seq` actually runs faster than `for ((i=1...))` so I don't think that has much if anything to do with the runtime

---

Interestingly, if I modify the for loop to:

```
for ((f=1;f<=$1;f++)); do
    isprime "$f" &
done | sort -n
```

It runs even quicker:

```
$ time ./script.sh 5000 >/dev/null

real    0m5.995s
user    0m33.229s
sys     0m6.382s
```

Comment: First thought: How about CPU usage in either case?

Comment: CPU usage peaked at about 20% with the for loop and about 60% with GNU parallel.

Comment: How many cpus do you have?

Comment: @icarus: I have a single 2.7GHz four core i7

Comment: So a 4 core i7 should hope to get with hyperthreading perhaps a 6x speedup. So then one needs to factor in the overhead of parallel starting processes. With 5000 processes taking about 30 seconds, each process is taking about 50ms on average. On this class of machine it should take about 1ms to start up a new bash, so there is quite a lot to explain away. The algorithm is truly horrible of course, testing all the numbers up to n rather than up to sqrt(n), so looking at 4999 for example will require nearly 5000 divisions rather than 70.

Comment: @icarus: Yes the function is intentionally not optimized in an attempt to show a bigger difference between single threading and running in parallel.

Comment: These cases will totally dominate the time, in contrast testing 4998 will fail in the first test. On a much much slower machine isprime 4999 takes about 0.09 seconds.  However there are not enough primes below 5000 (669) to explain the 30 seconds, so the overhead must be due to parallel. This is supported by the  6 seconds to create the 5000 jobs to calculate them in parallel.

Comment: So the conclusion is that parallel takes about 400ms to start a bash, run a function that should take a few ms to run on average, and reap the process. In general you should arrange for jobs to do more work and have fewer jobs, but I am surprised by the overhead.

Comment: I just ran you first program on an Intel(R) Core(TM) M-5Y10c CPU clamped at 500MHz. It did it in 22.5 seconds. It I let it go up to 2GHz it does it in 8.9 seconds. Is your machine heavily loaded?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor: Not really, sitting around 5-10%

Comment: I would try creating 3 separate sections for numeric ranges to see if that has an effect on how the script is being processed.  This way you could eliminate the theory that, perhaps, the script is being run sequentially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU Parallel spends 2-10 ms overhead per job. It can be lowered a bit by using `-u`, but that means you may get output from different jobs mixed.

GNU Parallel is not ideal if your jobs are in the ms range and runtime matters: The overhead will often be too big.

You can spread the overhead to multiple cores by running multiple GNU Parallels:

```
seq 5000 | parallel --pipe --round-robin -N100 parallel isprime
```

You still pay the overhead, but now you at least have more cores to pay with.

A better way would be to change `isprime` so that it takes multiple inputs and thus takes longer to run:

```
isprime() {
  _isprime () {
      local n=$1
      ((n==1)) && return 1
      for ((i=2;i<n;i++)); do
          if ((n%i==0)); then
              return 1
          fi
      done
      printf '%d\n' "$n"
  }
  for t in "$@"; do
    _isprime $t
  done
}
export -f isprime

seq 5000 | parallel -X isprime
# If you do not care about order, this is faster because higher numbers always take more time
seq 5000 | parallel --shuf -X isprime
```

Comment: With the new `isprime()` exported, this:  `seq 5000 |shuf| parallel -N1250 isprime | sort -n` really runs faster: 1.9 s (compared to 5s or 2.5s in my answer). WITHOUT `shuf |` (or `--shuf`) it takes longer (2.7s). Thanks for that simple syntax `parallel -X FUNC`. Is it so hard to find a better example? Now that for once it is not IO-limited, it is a slowed-down algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

I will not mention optimising `is_prime` iterate to squrare_root of (n).

I suspect that the version with parallel, is spending a significant amount of time starting processes. Therefore break it up into bigger chunks. e.g. n/Number_of_cpus should be the fastest (if each chunk takes the same time). Try a few chunk sizes, see what happens.

You will have to adapt your script to take  lower and increment.

e.g. arrange for parallel to run (if you have 5 cores).

```
./script    0 1000 &
./script 1000 1000 &
./script 2000 1000 &
./script 3000 1000 &
./script 4000 1000 &
```

Comment: Interestingly iterating to the square root is actually slower (probably due to the fact that it has to spawn another process for awk or bc for each number).

Comment: @jesse_b How does `for((i=2;i*i<=n;i++))` compare?

Comment: @icarus: That makes the for loop run in 0.6 seconds but parallel still takes 28-29.

Comment: Using pure awk though I can do up to 50k in .2 seconds :p

Answer (score 0):

By changing the main for loop:

```
for ((f=1;f<=$1;f+=2)); do
    isprime $f &
    isprime $((f+1))
done
```

it runs a bit faster

```
]# time ./jj.sh 5000 |wc
    669     669    3148

real    0m2.537s
user    0m8.109s
sys     0m1.374s
```

than without the `&`:

```
real    0m5.758s
user    0m5.761s
sys     0m0.007s
```

or with only background calls `&`:

```
real    0m3.298s
user    0m10.743s
sys     0m1.869s
```

So while the ampersand took you from 28s to 5s, I went from 5s to 3s.

I also tried 2 with ampersand and 1 without, but this is already getting slower.

---

```
]# time ./jj.sh 5000 |wc
^C

real    0m17.668s
user    0m17.576s
sys     0m1.344s
```

Dramatic slow down (see the ^C) if the ampersand is on the second call only:

```
for ((f=1;f<=$1;f+=2)); do
    isprime $f
    isprime $((f+1)) &
done
```

This seems a bit confusing.

---

By using the found prime numbers only as divisors you can speed up by factor 20:

```
max=5000
max2=75
primes=('3')
echo '2'; echo '3'

for ((n=5; n<max; n+=2))
do  size=${#primes[@]}
    for ((pi=0; pi<=$size; pi++))
    do  p=${primes[$pi]}
        if (( $n % $p == 0 ))
        then break
        fi
        if (( $p * $p > $n ))
        then echo $n
             (( $n < $max2 )) && primes+=("$n")
             break
        fi
    done
done
```

This gives:

```
]# time . prim.sh |wc
    669     669    3148

real    0m0.126s
user    0m0.142s
sys     0m0.001s
```

And the same thing in perl:

```
]# time perl prim.pl | wc
    668    1336    6486

real    0m0.008s
user    0m0.009s
sys     0m0.001s
```

(first line looks like `*** 3`, so `wc` output is normal)

But this algorithm is more difficult to parallelize: `isprime()` has to have access to the (growing) list of prime numbers (up to sqrt).

Maybe `factor` (a command fighting against section 6 :) would be useful as a standard functional unit. Then you can feed it with different "chunks".

```
]# time seq 2 5000 |factor |sed '/ .* /d' |cut -f1 -d':' |wc 
    669     669    3148

real    0m0.008s
user    0m0.014s
sys     0m0.005s
```

The `sed` deletes lines with more than one space (i.e. more than one factor).

But then again, it is too fast to be helped:

```
]# time seq 900000000002 900000005000 | factor  |wc
   4999   26848  163457

real    0m0.031s
user    0m0.035s
sys     0m0.003s
```

Comment: The question is about optimizing GNU parallel, calculating prime numbers is only an example.